# Calculate size in cm relative to objects in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I do know the height and width of this stairway.
The width is 2.8 meters, and the height, from the devider right bellow the image up to the ceiling, is 3.08 meters.

What I would like to do is making this image proportionally 2 meters in width relative to the wall it will be hanged on.
And place it about 40 cm up from the wall-"devider"...

Is this possible using Adobe Photoshop CC?

[image]

Comment: What's the size of the wall in this image? Looks like a simple rule of 3 calculation

Comment: The width is 2.8 meters, and the height, from the devider right bellow the image up to the ceiling, is 3.08 meters.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd do that like this:

1) resize the image so that the staircase wall would be easy to use for metrics, I decided to go with 560px (`2.8m*200`, so `1m` is `200px`)

[image]

2) So the image should be 400px (`2m*200`) and 80px (`0.4m*200`) above the divider:

[image]

3) There's some perspective distortion so I'll put the image in perspective

[image]

4) and a shadow

[image]

A quick test from the corner of the image to the wall... yup, `80px` so it's `0.4m` like it should be

[image]